# .env with next.js on local

Tags: environment-variables, next.js

I have 2 files about `.env`

**.env.local**

```
STAGE=local
API=http://localhost:3333
```

**.env.dev**

```
STAGE=dev
API=https://dev.api.domain.com
```

I want to seperate them as `package.json`'s script

What I want

```
"script": {
    "start-local": ".env.local && next",
    "start-dev": ".env.dev && next"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load a specific `.env` file by some env variable.

For example:

```
"script": {
    "start-local": "NODE_ENV=local next",
    "start-dev": "NODE_ENV=dev next"
}
```

This will define the `NODE_ENV` environment variable, then based on it, you can use [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) lib to load the proper file.

```js
// next.config.js
const dotEnv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');

const envFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`); // this will have the path to the proper `.env` file

dotEnv.config({ path: envFilePath }); 

module.exports = {
  ...
}
```